# Python selenium can't get text from website

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm writing a code that uses https://www.deepl.com/translator to translate english movie titles to polish (since it's the only translator i know that doesn't translate them literally) but I'm unable to extract translated text from website.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panelTranslateText"]/div[2]/section[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ol/li[1]/button').click()
print("polish confirmed")

WebDriverWait(driver, 3)

translation = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'target-dummydiv').get_attribute("textContent")
WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
print("translation found")
print(translation)
print(len(translation))
```

The code runs smoothly until it's time to print out the translated text. It returns 2 character long blank string.

```
input text to translate
textarea found
sending text
text has been sent
language choice clicked
search bar found
polish inserted
polish confirmed
translation found


2
```

Here is the HTML code where the translated text is located.

```
<div class="lmt__inner_textarea_container" title="Kliknij na słowo, aby wyświetlić tłumaczenia alternatywne ">
   <textarea aria-labelledby="translation-results-heading" class="lmt__textarea lmt__target_textarea lmt__textarea_base_style" data-gramm_editor="false" dl-test="translator-target-input" autocomplete="off" lang="pl-PL"></textarea>
   <div id="target-dummydiv" aria-hidden="true" class="lmt__textarea lmt__textarea_dummydiv" lang="pl-PL">Stranger Things</div>
</div>
```

I have also tried using `get_attribute("innerText")` but it doesn't work either. Is there any other way to extract this text?

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'target-dummydiv').get_attribute("innerHTML")` or `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'target-dummydiv').text`

Comment: Unfortunately none of these return the text. ```driver.find_element(By.ID, 'target-dummydiv').get_attribute("innerHTML")``` returns the same blank string with 2 characters and ```driver.find_element(By.ID, 'target-dummydiv').text``` returns blank string with 0 characters.

Comment: Can you show full code, please? Because I have tried your peace of code with `https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/pl/Starager%20Things`with this url and get nice result.

Comment: ```chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
                          service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.deepl.com/translator")
driver.maximize_window()
print("input text to translate")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
wpisz_tekst = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panelTranslateText"]/div[2]/section[1]/div[3]/div[2]/textarea')
print("textarea found")```

Comment: ```print("sending text")
wpisz_tekst.send_keys("Stranger Things")
print("text has been sent")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panelTranslateText"]/div[2]/section[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/button').click()
print("language choice clicked")
find_pl = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="panelTranslateText"]/div[2]/section[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')
print("search bar found")
find_pl.send_keys("polski")
print("polish inserted")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panelTranslateText"]/div[2]/section[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ol/li[1]/button').click()```

Comment: ```print("polish confirmed")
WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
translation = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'target-dummydiv').text
WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
print("translation found")
print(translation)
print(len(translation))```

Comment: Here is the full code